# Facebook Open Graph posts layout switches between small image and large image

Tags: facebook-opengraph

We are currently integrating Facebook Open graph with our web and mobile applications. We have couple of stories created in the open graph sections.
Each story has a custom action and a custom object.
The object contains an image thats getting shared when an action is posted.

All images are of type png and width:201px height 201px.
We found that the minimum allowed image size is 200px. So this should be acceptable.

Open graph layout for both stories are "item" layout in "Edit Attachment" section.

Objects are posted to the facebook API as opengraph objects.
graph.facebook.com/objects/{appname}:{object_name}/{accesstoken}

This endpoint returns an opengraph object id which then is sent as part 
Opengraph action post.
graph.facebook.com/{appname}:{action_name}/{accesstoken}

The content is getting posted without a problem. The issue is only with the way the posts are getting displayed.
The layout switches between large image and small image(preferred) layouts.

The layouts displayed in Facebook:

[image]

Layout switching is completely Random. Sometimes all posts comes in the small image layout but then for another Facebook user they display as large image layouts.

We are trying to find out how to force Facebook to show the small image layout.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you found on that documentation?

Comment: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) here under small images heading it says that images below 600 x 315 px should post as in a small image layout

Comment: we are already sending images that should qualify as small images. Smallest accepted one is 200px and we are sending 201px which is still way below the mentioned small image size of 600x 315px

Comment: Not the image that is being sent, but rather how you are retrieving it, and displaying it. Anyhow, check for more samples and details on the documentation, since you are showing little to no effort in this question. There is no code, no layout, no nothing to aid what you are doing.

Comment: We finally decided on adding the recommended large image size of 1200x630px. The posts does get switched between the layouts but they don't  crop the image content anymore

Comment: So, instead of understand the issue you are having you are "taking shots" at the problem, and just continuing the mistakes you were making?